# How to put pushbutton inside the QMenu or QAction control?

Tags: qt, user-interface, user-controls

I need to put a `QPushButton` inside a `QMenu`. Is it possible and, if so, then how?

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? A push button inside a menu sounds like a very strange UI element - how should it work?

Comment: New QAction should be added to QMenu after button pushed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

QWidgetAction is what you are looking for. This is what is on qt docs

> The QWidgetAction class extends QAction by an interface for inserting custom widgets into action based containers

So basically it gives a custom UI to QAction according to what QWidget you pass to it.
I have used QWidgetAction to show checkbox as QMenu items.

```
QCheckBox *chkBox = new QCheckBox(menu);
chkBox ->setText("MyCheckBox");
QWidgetAction *chkBoxAction= new QWidgetAction(menu);
chkBoxAction->setDefaultWidget(chkBox);
menu->addAction(chkBoxAction);
```

You can then handle signals from checkbox accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a menu item to have a state, you may use Checkable property of QAction:

```
rotateAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/Mouse/Rotate.png"), tr("&Rotate"), this);
rotateAct->setCheckable(true);
```