# How to create a new menu with style and button with QMenu

Tags: qt, qmenu

I need to create a menu example like this when we click to the plus icon
[image: menu]

I just created the text.

```
QMenu *menu = new QMenu(this);
menuicd->addAction("Choose the job from:");
menuicd->addAction("Our job portal");
menuicd->addAction("Our database");
menuicd->addAction("University website");
ui.plusbutton->setMenu(menu);
```

How can I make the white text with blue background for the options? And how can i add the cancel button in this menu?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704668/how-to-put-pushbutton-inside-the-qmenu-or-qaction-control this can help you for the cancel button

Comment: Did you inspect QToolButton (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html) with its `setMenu` method?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a custom context menu you can use a style sheet
like that:

```
QMenu
{
    border: 1px solid #76797C;
    color: #eff0f1;
    margin: 2px;
}

QMenu::icon
{
    margin: 5px;
}

QMenu::item
{
    padding: 5px 30px 5px 30px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid transparent; /* reserve space for selection border */
}
```

But this image is like a [QDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. But how can I set 2 types of item ? Because if you look at the menu, the first line is `Choose the job from:`. This line does not have blue background. So how can I do this?