# Qt dropdown menu with text under the button

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8

I am working on a drop-down menu with C++ Qt4.8.
This is the repo I used for testing [Qt-Ribbon-Widget](https://github.com/martijnkoopman/Qt-Ribbon-Widget).
The current menu contains rows of icon in the left, and text in the right.

[text in the right of the icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXpPz.png)

I want to make the icon as same size as the menu button, and with the text under the icon. here is my drawing.

[text under the icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myOLw.png)

This is the code for the adding menu to the button

```cpp
  // Create 'Open file' button
  QToolButton *openFileButton = new QToolButton(this);
  openFileButton->setText(tr("File"));
  openFileButton->setToolTip(tr("Open file or directory"));
  openFileButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/icons/add_folder_2.svg"));

  // Create dropdown menu
  openFileButton->setPopupMode(QToolButton::MenuButtonPopup);
  QMenu *menu = new RibbonIconMenu("Title");
  menu->addAction(QIcon(":/icons/file_2.svg"), "Recent file 1");
  menu->addAction(QIcon(":/icons/file_2.svg"), "Recent file 2");
  menu->addAction(QIcon(":/icons/file_2.svg"), "Recent file 3");

  // Add this menu to the 'Open file' button
  openFileButton->setMenu(menu);

  ui->ribbonTabWidget->addButton("Project", openFileButton);
```

the icon and the text are pass separately in the `addAction()`

And this is the code for the custom menu, which is derived from QMenu.

```cpp
#include <QMenu>
#include <QObject>

class RibbonIconMenu : public QMenu
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    RibbonIconMenu(const QString sName, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
};

RibbonIconMenu::RibbonIconMenu(const QString sName, QWidget *parent)
    : QMenu(sName, parent)
{

    // Set stylesheet
    QString styleSheetText = QString(
          // maybe?
        );

    setStyleSheet(styleSheetText);
}
```

According to [Qt Documentation - The Style Sheet Syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html), "Qt Style Sheet terminology and syntactic rules are almost identical to those of HTML CSS.". I'm not familiar with HTML/CSS, but I found some HTML/CSS solution is using the HTML way. I wonder if there's CSS property type or some Qt's way to solve it?

update:
I use `QWidgetAction` and solve it. See [How to put pushbutton inside the QMenu or QAction control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704668/how-to-put-pushbutton-inside-the-qmenu-or-qaction-control).

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    QToolButton *openDatabaseButton = new QToolButton;
    openDatabaseButton->setText(tr("Database"));
    openDatabaseButton->setToolTip(tr("Connect to database"));
    openDatabaseButton->setIcon(QIcon(":/icons/add_database_2.svg"));
    openDatabaseButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
    openDatabaseButton->setMinimumSize(48, 48);
    openDatabaseButton->setAutoRaise(true);
    openDatabaseButton->setIconSize(QSize(32,32));
    openDatabaseButton->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
    QWidgetAction *toolButtonAction = new QWidgetAction(menu);
    toolButtonAction->setDefaultWidget(openDatabaseButton);
    menu->addAction(toolButtonAction);
}
openFileButton->setMenu(menu);
```

Comment: Customize your tool button: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtoolbutton.html#toolButtonStyle-prop